# yacc/bison tokens error. '>>>' and '>>' both assigned number 62

Tags: bison

I do something like this in my code

```
CmpExpr:
      rval '<<' rval           { $$ = $1 << $3; }
    | rval '>>' rval           { $$ = $1 >> $3; }
    | rval '>>>' rval          { $$ = (unsigned)($1) >> ($3); }
    ;
```

the warning i get is

```
tokens '>>>' and '>>' both assigned number 62
```

How do i make it use different tokens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%TOKEN LSHIFT RSHIFT RRSHIFT
```

in lex write

```
"<<"        { return LSHIFT; }
">>"        { return RSHIFT; }
">>>"       { return RRSHIFT; }
```

then you can write

```
CmpExpr:
      rval LSHIFT  rval           { $$ = $1 << $3; }
    | rval RSHIFT  rval           { $$ = $1 >> $3; }
    | rval RRSHIFT rval           { $$ = (unsigned)($1) >> ($3); }
```

I think you can write "<<" instead of LSHIFT since it compiles but i have no idea if it runs differently

Comment: Yes, you can use "<<" in the grammar file, it's exactly the same.

Comment: Using `"<<"` generates a unique token for the shift, but it does not generate a definition for that token in the `.tab.h` file, so there's no easy way to produce that token in your lexer...

Answer (score 3):

You can only have a single character between the quotes in bison -- any multiple character token must be recognized by the lexer as such and returned as a single token, as described by acidzombie

When you put multiple characters in quotes in bison (as you have done), it essentially just ignores all except for the first, which means '>>' and '>>>' are really the same token (the same as '>'), giving the error you see.  This is not terribly useful behavior, but was inherited from the original yacc program.

Comment: I dont know if you notice i asked and answered this question ;)